# expect pass password through file for automation in shell script

Tags: shell, automation, expect

I have the script (test.sh) i which i am using expect to pass the password to the user. I want the username and password should be used from the local file (tmp.txt). Please guide me to do the same.

cat test.sh

```
expect "*User_ID*" 
send "testuser\r" 
expect "*Password*" 
send "passw0rd\r" 
expect eof

cat tmp.txt
testuser
password
```

Answer (score 0):

In expect you would:

```
#!/usr/bin/env expect

# read the file
set fh [open tmp.txt]
gets $fh user
gets $fh pass
close $fh

# launch the process
spawn some command here

# now you can automate the login
expect "*User_ID*" 
send "$user\r" 
expect "*Password*" 
send "$pass\r" 
expect eof
```

TODO: Error handling and input validation

Comment: Thank for the help... Its is working.                                                                ```#!/usr/bash
password=`hdfs dfs -cat /data/pwd.txt`
host="IP"
username=`hdfs dfs -cat /data/user.txt`
/usr/bin/expect << EOF
spawn ssh -X $username@$host
set pass $password;
puts "pwd = \$pass"
*** Your Command***
EOF

Comment: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)